# Ubuntu 16.04 takes very long time to boot on Dell Precision 5510

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 16.04, dell

My ubuntu install takes an unusually long time to boot (like 2 minutes), considering it’s on a Dell Precision 5510 with i7 processor. The `dmesg` thing shows a really big time gap <strike>having to do with ACPI something</strike>. I tried switching to the proprietary NVidia driver and I had the same problem so I don’t think it’s nouveau’s fault.

How do I fix this?

```
[    4.976738] hid-multitouch 0018:06CB:7A13.0003: input,hidraw2: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [DLL06E5:01 06CB:7A13] on i2c-DLL06E5:01
[    9.735326] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    9.735915] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[    9.735918] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    9.736038] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
[    9.736040] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
[    9.736054] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
[    9.737462] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
[   94.677574] ACPI: Invalid package element [0]: got number, expecting [R]
[   94.677577] _ART package 0 is invalid, ignored
[   94.677591] ACPI: Invalid package element [0]: got number, expecting [R]
[   94.677592] _ART package 0 is invalid, ignored
```

here is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`

```
       787ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       559ms gpu-manager.service
       336ms lightdm.service
       186ms dev-nvme0n1p8.device
       113ms accounts-daemon.service
       112ms ModemManager.service
        94ms systemd-localed.service
        81ms boot-efi.mount
        77ms plymouth-start.service
        76ms systemd-logind.service
```

EDIT : tried @niry ’s suggestion turning acpi=off, it didn’t work. Looks like acpi isn’t to blame. This is what dmesg is outputting now:

```
[    4.713109] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    4.713860] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1406642 usecs
[    4.713888] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    4.725868] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11710 usecs
[    4.726328] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[    4.727871] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    4.729019] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16)
[   93.218918] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   93.218921] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   93.218923] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   93.304637] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

EDIT 2: I unplugged all USB devices including the wireless mouse but it still has the same problem. Here’s part of the `dmesg` output with `debug ignore_loglevel log_buf_len=16M`:

(Also why is this being marked as off topic, I said it was on the official 16.04 not the 16.10 that was a typo)

```
[    5.083674] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.130155] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
[    5.130264] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-19)
[    5.145481] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[    5.150813] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[    5.151126] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[    5.151708] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[    5.153827] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[    5.163421] input: DLL06E5:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-19/i2c-DLL06E5:01/0018:06CB:7A13.0002/input/input18
[    5.163525] hid-multitouch 0018:06CB:7A13.0002: input,hidraw1: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [DLL06E5:01 06CB:7A13] on i2c-DLL06E5:01
[    9.749389] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    9.749982] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[    9.749985] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[    9.750109] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
[    9.750111] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
[    9.750126] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
[    9.751485] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
[   94.566348] systemd-journald[310]: Sent WATCHDOG=1 notification.
[   94.584143] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.591574] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.592148] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.592558] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.595552] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.595854] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.596193] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.596423] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.596680] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.596917] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.597515] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.597871] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.598969] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.599158] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.599457] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.599628] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.600074] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.601049] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.601594] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.602088] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.603955] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.604117] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.604721] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
[   94.605534] systemd-journald[310]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `systemd-analyze blame`

Comment: @ByteCommander done

Comment: We currently do not support 16.10 as it is currently in active development.  Issues with 16.10 should be reported on Launchpad for developers to address them.

Comment: OH DID I WRITE 10 I MEANT 04 i typed it wrong sorry

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions , scroll down to "Common Kernel Options" and try the ACPI options

Comment: Start with the most aggressive option to see if it is helping: `acpi=off`, if it did help narrow it down: `acpi=ht` etc.

Comment: @niry i just tried that, didn't work. edited question ^

Comment: Try `debug ignore_loglevel log_buf_len=16M` in the boot options

Comment: did that. didn’t work. Also tried disabling bluetooth in the settings. The gap is still between `nouveau ….….…. :  DRM: suspending kernel object tree` and `systemd-journald[326]: Sent WATCHDOG=1 notification`

Comment: The options above meant to give more data, not to solve the problem. The gap seems to be changing which means whatever is going on it isn't emitting logs.

Comment: try to disconnect all the usb and other devices (hard drives/ssd/thumb drives/printers/network/pointing devs. ETC.) that are not necessary for booting. It is possible that some unknown hardware is causing this, but it could be on the motherboard - next would be to disable integrated devices (audio/network/ports ETC.) in the bios. Keep `debug ignore_loglevel log_buf_len=16M` kernel options so you'll know better what is going on.

Comment: i unplugged all of them and it didn't work

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question as the OP clarified that it is indeed 16.04.